Why its adding one more day to the End date?
I have a problem in my script, why its keep adding one more day, if the duration of the training is one day for example, it suggest dates for me as 1/7/2024 to 2/7/2024.


function formatDate(date) {
  return date.toDateString();
}

function calculateEndDate(startDate, numDays) {
  console.log(`Calculating end date for startDate: ${formatDate(startDate)}, numDays: ${numDays}`);

  var endDate = new Date(startDate);
  var daysAdded = 0;

  while (daysAdded < numDays - 1) {
    endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 1);
    var day = endDate.getDay();

    // Skip weekends (Saturday = 6, Sunday = 0)
    if (day === 0 || day === 6) {
      console.log(`Skipping weekend: ${formatDate(endDate)}`);
      continue;
    }

    daysAdded++;
    console.log(`Added day: ${formatDate(endDate)}, daysAdded: ${daysAdded}`);
  }

  // Adjust endDate to account for weekends
  if (endDate.getDay() === 6) { // Saturday
    endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() - 1);
  } else if (endDate.getDay() === 0) { // Sunday
    endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() - 2);
  }

  console.log(`Final calculated end date: ${formatDate(endDate)}`);
  return endDate;
}

let start = new Date(2024,6,1); // 1 Jul 2024
let days = 1;    // days to add

console.log(calculateEndDate(start, days).toDateString());




I don't see where it's adding another day. I do find it odd that if the start date was set as a weekend, the end date occurs in the past.

Your log output should give you insight as to how the day is being added. But in general you should avoid trying to roll your own date arithmetic like this. The Javascript Date object has lots of problems. Use something like luxon or date-fns, which handle date math for you.

@showaltb—there are no issues with how the OP is doing the arithmetic or with Date objects. There is an issue with the business rules for adding days to a date though. The OP wants to add business days (i.e. exclude weekends) such that adding 1 day goes to the next business day. In many scenarios, adding 1 day should return the same day, e.g. a 1 day training course typically starts and ends on the same day. However, a 1 night hotel stay likely ends on the day following. Business rules are the primary source of issues arising from date arithmetic, not the Date object itself.

Your code does what you expect. calculateEndDate(new Date(2024,6,1), 1) returns a date for 1 Jul 2024. What you haven't accounted for though is that if the start date is a Sat or Sun, you put the end date back to Friday. You need to check whether the start is a Sat or Sun first and deal with that problem (throw, return undefined, set to prior Fri or following Mon, whatever) before adding days.

If you go calculateEndDate('1/7/2024', 1), you'll receive new Date ('1/5/2024'), which is before the startdate.
Why?
We never enter the loop.
The 7th of january 2024 was a sunday (endDate.getDay() === 0) so we return endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() - 2);.
Simple approach
just going day by day until you have reached the desired number of days and see where you land:


export function calculateEndDate(startDate: string, numDays: number) {
  const currentDate = new Date(startDate);
  let daysOfTraining = 0;
  const isEndDateReached = daysOfTraining !== numDays

  while (!isEndDateReached) {
    const day = currentDate.getDay();
    const date = currentDate.getDate();
    if(day !== 0 && day !== 6) daysOfTraining++

    // set current date to tomorrow
    if(!isEndDateReached) currentDate.setDate(date + 1);
  }

  return currentDate;
}



More performant approach
Skipping the loop by working with a reference date in the future:


const DAYS_IN_A_WEEK = 7;
const skipDays = (date: Date, numberOfDays: number) => new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + numberOfDays);
const skipWeeks = (date: Date, numberOfDays: number) => skipDays(date, numberOfDays * DAYS_IN_A_WEEK);

export function calculateEndDate(startDateString: string, numDays: number) {
  const startDate = new Date(startDateString);

  // eg: for 6 training days we can go to the next week already
  // for 5 training days, we need to o to the next week and than go back to the previous working day
  const referenceDate = skipWeeks(startDate, Math.floor(numDays / 5))
  const referenceDay = referenceDate.getDay();
  const remainingDays = numDays % 5;

  const isSunday = referenceDay === 0;
  const isMonday = referenceDay === 1;
  const isTuesday = referenceDay === 2;
  const isWednesday = referenceDay === 3;
  const isThursday = referenceDay === 4;
  const isFriday = referenceDay === 5;
  const isSaturday = referenceDay === 6;
  const isWorkDay = isMonday || isTuesday || isWednesday || isThursday || isFriday;

  // If the number of days are dividable by 5, we overshot, and we need to go back to the previous working day
  if(remainingDays === 0 && isMonday) return skipDays(referenceDate, -3)
  if(remainingDays === 0 && !isMonday && !isSunday) return skipDays(referenceDate, -1)
  if(remainingDays === 0 && isSunday) return skipDays(referenceDate, -2)

  // Otherwise, you need to have the remaining days, starting from the reference date
  if(remainingDays === 1 && isWorkDay) return referenceDay
  if(remainingDays === 1 && isSaturday) return skipDays(referenceDate, 2)
  if(remainingDays === 1 && isSunday) return skipDays(referenceDate, 1)

  if(remainingDays === 2 && (isMonday || isTuesday || isWednesday || isThursday)) return skipDays(referenceDate, 1)
  if(remainingDays === 2 && (isFriday || isSaturday)) return skipDays(referenceDate, 3)
  if(remainingDays === 2 && isSunday) return skipDays(referenceDate, 2)

  if(remainingDays === 3 && (isMonday || isTuesday || isWednesday)) return skipDays(referenceDate, 2)
  if(remainingDays === 3 && (isThursday || isFriday || isSaturday)) return skipDays(referenceDate, 4)
  if(remainingDays === 3 && isSunday) return skipDays(referenceDate, 3)

  if(remainingDays === 4 && (isMonday || isTuesday)) return skipDays(referenceDate, 3)
  if(remainingDays === 4 && (isWednesday|| isThursday || isFriday || isSaturday)) return skipDays(referenceDate, 5)
  if(remainingDays === 4 && isSunday) return skipDays(referenceDate, 4)
}



It's clear that the first approach is far more readable/understandable. For the second one, you really need go over it case by case to understand. For these kind of problems, you need to work methodically and use clear variable names.

I think you are assuming the peculiar US format of m/d/y, however I think in the OP that 1/7/2024 is 1 July 2024 (given that it's currently July and other info in the OP). You are correct however in that if the code doesn't correctly deal with start dates on Sat or Sun.
